# Case statement in where clause not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Friends..

I am using stored procedure in which there is an optional parameter **@equal** and default value is NULL. If user give some value to the parameter SQL query has to be changed. I am trying to use Case in Where clause. but its showing some error. 
Help me with proper syntax or with better logic

My requirement is When user doesn't give value for **@equal** then
FiscalYear<@yr
Else
FiscalYear<=@yr

```
Select BankCode,(SUM(Debit)-SUM(Credit)) Amt
From vwDailyData 
Where Pname=@ParishName and FiscalYear< (CASE WHEN @equal IS NULL THEN @yr ELSE '='+@yr) 
and BankCode<>'Cash'
Group By BankCode
```

**Modified Question**

```
Select BankCode,(SUM(Debit)-SUM(Credit)) Amt
From vwDailyData 
Where Pname=@ParishName AND (CASE WHEN @equal IS NULL THEN FiscalYear < @yr ELSE FiscalYear <= @yr END)
and BankCode<>'Cash'
Group By BankCode
```

Error statement
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spDisplayBankConsolidate, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two errors in your condition:

- `CASE` expression lacks `END`, and
- You cannot supply a different operator inside a `CASE` expression.

The condition should look like this:

```
WHERE Pname=@ParishName AND 
((@equal IS NULL AND FiscalYear < @yr) OR (@equal IS NOT NULL AND FiscalYear <= @yr))
AND BankCode<>'Cash'
```

Note the `@equal IS NULL` and `@equal IS NOT NULL` conditions in two parts of the `OR` expression. Since the two are mutually exclusive, only one side of the `OR` will be deciding what rows to include in the query result.

Comment: Or you could use ... `AND CASE WHEN @equal IS NULL THEN FiscalYear < @yr ELSE FiscalYear <= @yr END` if you want to stick with a `CASE` statement.

Comment: I am getting this error
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spDisplayBankConsolidate, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spDisplayBankConsolidate, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @JineshSam Could you post your new query somewhere? It looks like there's a missing or extra parenthesis somewhere in the query.

Comment: I have modified the question with your suggestion.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i am getting the same result for both inputs

Comment: @JineshSam What do you mean by "both inputs"?

Comment: ie, if @equal is NULL or NOT NULL the result is same

Comment: @JineshSam Do you have rows in your data where `FiscalYear` is equal to `@yr` that you are passing? Do these additional records not show up when `@equals` is set to a non-null value?

Comment: S it has 
Select (SUM(Debit)-SUM(Credit)) Amt
From vwDailyData 
WHERE Pname=@ParishName  AND FiscalYear<2013 the result is 0 and
<=2013 the reult is 477582.00

Comment: @JineshSam Could you set up a small demo on sqlfiddle.com? The query from my answer should produce proper results, assuming that you copied the parts correctly, and set up proper values into `@yr` and `@equals`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Sorry dear the query is working.Since i use group by i didn't feel the change in first 2 3 rows. when i take the sum of the column i understood my mistake. Thanks for your support and  Valuable time.